# MacOS - How to achieve the same text effect as the Mac lock screen interface

Tags: macos

How to achieve the same text effect as the Mac lock screen interface:
[image]

I tried adding an NSTextField object to an NSVisualEffectView object, but it didn't work.

```
let visualEffectView = NSVisualEffectView(frame: view.bounds)
visualEffectView.material = .hudWindow
visualEffectView.state = .active
visualEffectView.appearance = NSAppearance(named: .darkAqua)
visualEffectView.wantsLayer = true
view.addSubview(visualEffectView)


let label = NSTextField(frame: visualEffectView.bounds)
label.stringValue = "Hello, World!"
label.isEditable = false
label.isBordered = false
label.backgroundColor = NSColor.clear
label.textColor = NSColor.white
label.font = NSFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 80)
label.wantsLayer = true
visualEffectView.addSubview(label)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to mask the `NSVisualEffectView` rather than add the label as a subview of the effect view. You can do this by using the `maskImage` property of `NSVisualEffectView` where the alpha channel of the image determines what is shown: opaque pixels are shown, transparent pixels are removed. You can snapshot your label to get an image of it then apply that image to `maskImage`.

For example:

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let imageView = NSImageView(image: NSImage(named: "screenshot")!)
        imageView.frame = view.bounds
        imageView.wantsLayer = true
        view.addSubview(imageView)

        let visualEffectView = NSVisualEffectView(frame: view.bounds)
        visualEffectView.blendingMode = .withinWindow
        visualEffectView.material = .light
        visualEffectView.state = .active
        visualEffectView.appearance = NSAppearance(named: .darkAqua)
        visualEffectView.wantsLayer = true
        view.addSubview(visualEffectView)

        let label = NSTextField(frame: visualEffectView.bounds)
        label.stringValue = "Hello, World!"
        label.isEditable = false
        label.isBordered = false
        label.backgroundColor = NSColor.clear
        label.textColor = NSColor.white
        label.font = NSFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 80)
        label.wantsLayer = true
        label.layer?.frame = visualEffectView.layer?.bounds ?? .zero
        label.layer?.position = visualEffectView.layer?.position ?? .zero
        visualEffectView.maskImage = label.snapshot

    }
}

extension NSView {
    var snapshot: NSImage? {
        guard let window = self.window else { return nil }
        let backingScaleFactor = window.backingScaleFactor
        let scaledBounds = NSRect(x: self.bounds.origin.x * backingScaleFactor, y: self.bounds.origin.y * backingScaleFactor, width: self.bounds.size.width * backingScaleFactor, height: self.bounds.size.height * backingScaleFactor)
        let bitmapRep = self.bitmapImageRepForCachingDisplay(in: self.bounds)!
        bitmapRep.size = scaledBounds.size

        self.cacheDisplay(in: self.bounds, to: bitmapRep)

        let image = NSImage(size: scaledBounds.size)
        image.addRepresentation(bitmapRep)

        return image
    }
}
```

Will yield:

[image: Screenshot of visual effect view masked by text of "Hello, World!" over background image]